# 2D character tile based movement problem

Tags: animation, sprites

I am making a Super Mario like 2D platformer and I've encountered a problem. 
I need to move this sprite :

[image]

When a player presses the right key, the sprite moves by 32 px to the right. 
The process of moving the sprite is as follows :

- The sprite begins in a `StandingIdleFirstStep` state (Image 1).
- Then the sprite enters a transition state (Image 2). The sprite is moved by 16 px to the right. This state is visible for 256 ms.
- Finally, the sprite ends the movement in a `StandingIdleSecondStep` and has moved 32 px from its starting position (Image 3 - first and third step images differ).

During this entire process, the user cannot interact with the sprite. I can feed the process with a approx. 30 ms delta per frame.

Currently I'm thinking about this solution :

1. User presses move right
2. Set `moving` flag to `true`
3. Move sprite by `x+=16 px`.
4. Update sprite animation
5. Draw everything

(after 256 ms)

1. Check `if currentAnimationImageIndex % 2 == 1`.
2. If true (odd image, can't stop there), move sprite by another `x+=16 px`.
3. Update sprite animation
4. Draw everything
5. Set `moving` flag to `false`

Comment: What's the question? And the problem you've encountered?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't know how to approach this. If I add the `StandingIdleFirstStep` and `StandingIdleSecondStep` to the animaton cycle (add time to their images) the process gets messed up (the cycle waits until the display time passes). If I don't add those two states to the animation, then what should I do with them?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd add time for them. They represent where the sprite *was* when it started the animation and where the sprite *will be* when the animation completes. Have you tried implementing your current solution? Implementing that will at least give you something to tinker with.

Comment: Trust me, computers nowadays are fast enough to draw everything many times per second. You dont have to optimize by not drawing too much

Comment: On a side note, why do his legs change color?

Comment: @Byte56 You're right, I am overthinking this. I didn't like this solution because it moves the sprite at one point without the user's consent. But I'll implement this, and work it from there.

Comment: @stas It's leg colour doesn't really change in-game, I only added the red leg to show that images 1 and 3 are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thinking this way:

**UI thread:**

1. User presses move right
2. Set `moving` flag to `true`

**Game Loop Thread, measure elapsed time between updates**

1. show current character sprite frame
2. if `moving` add elapsed time to total animation time, else show frame 1
3. if animation time < 256ms show frame 2, if animation time > 256ms show frame 3 (ando so on for longer walk)
4. update sprite position by distance (if it moves 128 pixels per second, move it 128 * elapsed time in seconds)
5. perform checks
6. draw everything

---

Don't try to do everything in one thread, don't let UI or waiting for another frame block the whole game.

Comment: Why does UI need its own thread? Having UI within the game loop does not imply one blocking the other.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but I believe it is so in most games. I did not express it very well. I wanted to say that "During this entire process, the user cannot interact with the sprite. " is not a good idea. User can change his mind just in that time and want to walk left etc.